# I have a bug where the player can still press x without in the triggerange of the Chest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The player spawns in a different location than the chest

**1.** So what it should do is first to go to Update Method which is obvious but it cant access the result of the first
if statement because **TouchingChestBoxCollider** is still **false** (at the beginning).

**2.** If the Player reaches the the trigger range of the Chest, then **TouchingChestBoxCollider = true**

**3.** Next it should go again to the Update() I know Update is called every frame but i want to make the order clear. The if Statement is now "valid" and **xIsPressed = true** so **OnTriggerStay2D** can go to DropDownItem and the rest is irelevant.

**What the Problem looks like :** i can still Press X outside the CircleCollider2D range of the Chest and when i already have reached the range the Chest, it drops the items even though it should do it when im in the in the range not outside (press x)
Do i have a mistake in the Code and if yes where pls help me

**What the Code should do at the end:** In the Range of The Chest you can press X and the items spawns
if **not** in **range** and you still press x and then go to the chest range it will not spawn BUT WHAT IT DOES XD.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChestOpener : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject ChestItSelf;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] itemsWeapon;

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] itemsMedi;

    [SerializeField]
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    [SerializeField]
    private Sprite openSprite, closeSprite;

    private int random;
    private Vector2 destination;
    private GameObject objectsWeapon;
    private GameObject objectsWeapon2;
    private GameObject objectsMedi;
    private bool HasItDropped = false;
    private bool MoveItemNow = false;
    private bool xIsPressed = false;
    private bool TouchingChestBoxCollider = false;

    private void Update()
    {        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X)  && TouchingChestBoxCollider == true)
        {
            xIsPressed = true;
        }
        if (MoveItemNow == true ) //it should always stay at the Update function or else it will not render the move (lag)
        {
            objectsWeapon.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(objectsWeapon.transform.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 4), 
                Time.deltaTime * 1f);
            objectsWeapon2.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(objectsWeapon2.transform.position, new Vector2(transform.position.x-2, transform.position.y - 4),
                Time.deltaTime * 1f);
        }  
    }
    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision) 
    {
        TouchingChestBoxCollider = true;
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player" && HasItDropped == false && xIsPressed == true)
        {
            DropDownItem();
        }
    }
    private void DropDownItem()
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = openSprite;
        random = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, itemsWeapon.Length);
        objectsWeapon = Instantiate(itemsWeapon[random], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        objectsWeapon2 = Instantiate(itemsWeapon[random], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        
        MoveItemNow = true; 
        HasItDropped = true;
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = closeSprite;
        Invoke("FareWellChest", 2f);
       
    }
    private void FareWellChest()
    {
        if (HasItDropped == true)
        {
            Destroy(ChestItSelf);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer but it still happens that the chest drops the item when i press x (outside the chest range). 
I press X (outside the chest range) and then i go to the chest range = it  still drops :( idk how to fix  that

Answer (score 0):

you seem to never ever reset `TouchingChestBoxCollider` and should probably do so in

```
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    TouchingChestBoxCollider = false;

    spriteRenderer.sprite = closeSprite;
    Invoke("FareWellChest", 2f);
}
```

and also never reset `xIsPressed` and should do so in

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision) 
{
    TouchingChestBoxCollider = true;
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !HasItDropped && xIsPressed)
    {
        DropDownItem();
    }

    xIsPressed = false;
}
```

---

Actually if instead of `OnTriggerStay2D` you rather used `OnTriggerEnter2D` in order to make relevant checks only once you could simplify the logic into

```
private void Update()
{        
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X)  && TouchingChestBoxCollider)
    {
        DropDownItem();
    }
    
    ...
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) 
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !HasItDropped)
    {
        TouchingChestBoxCollider = true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision) 
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        TouchingChestBoxCollider = false;
    }
}
```

so you wouldn't need the `xIsPressed` at all.

---

*In genera when dealing with Physics and Collision detection you should avoid moving any object via `Transform` in `Update` but rather go through the `Rigidbody2D` in `FixedUpdate`.*

Comment: Okay i will look more into it

Comment: ty derHugo or in german Danke dir hast was tolles gemacht^^